# Simulate android request (as from an android platform) from a postman

Tags: android, api, request, postman, simulation

Is it possible to simulate an android request from a postman, maybe to add some headers?

Comment: Yes. You can simulate via Talend API Tester or Postman. First you need to pass(Headers) like  content-type , token, cookies or any required parameter by thar APi also you need to define Request type like POST/GET etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can enter any key-value pairs you need and Postman will send them along with your request. As you type, Postman will prompt you with common options you can use to autocomplete your setup, such as `Content-Type`.

[image]

If you need more information you can follow the Postman Learning Center:

- [Sending your first request](https://learning.postman.com/docs/getting-started/sending-the-first-request/)
- [Building requests](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/requests/)

Comment: No value in this answer. The question is **how** you simulate using Postman or any other tools that request is made from an Android device.